# How to fix Flutter Android DarkActionBar not found

Tags: android, flutter

I have a Flutter app that is working fine in iOS, but will not compile in Android. I have tried to migrate to AndroidX and running it in android studio a few times, but it is still not compiling.

Here are the outputs from Android studio:

```
Android resource linking failed
/Users/isaiahscheel/CapstoneCode/mobile_hiking_app/build/app/intermediates/instant_run_merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:96: error: resource style/Theme/AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (aka com.example.mobilehikingapp:style/Theme/AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.
```

And then the output from VS Code

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 64 in debug mode...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Note: /Users/isaiahscheel/CapstoneCode/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.3.1+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

And I will also include my pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0" 

dependencies:

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.1+1 
  firebase_core: ^0.3.0

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  flutter_facebook_login: ^1.1.1
  http: ^0.12.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.0+2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.1+1
  flutter_slidable: "^0.4.9"
  url_launcher: ^5.0.2
  share: ^0.6.0+1
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.7
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^3.2.3595
  auto_size_text: ^1.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
  - assets/logo.png
```

Comment: The error is a manifest error. It does not look like it has anything to do with Android X.

Comment: open your project and in android app level gradle add this dependency "implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'"